# Django failing migration - Cannot query "peterson": Must be "User" instance

Tags: python, django, migration, django-migrations

I'm on Django 1.9, Python 3.6.  I made this migration to try and fill in UserProfiles for any users missing them.

But I'm getting the error below.

What's strange is the "user" variable seems to be a User instance.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import migrations
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


def create_missing_profiles(apps, schema_editor):
    UserProfile = apps.get_model("myapp", "UserProfile")
    for user in User.objects.all():
        UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', '0004_auto_20170721_0908'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_missing_profiles),
    ]
```

Error:

ValueError: Cannot query "peterson": Must be "User" instance.

Comment: You should get User via `get_model` as well, instead of importing  it.

Comment: I was wondering about that.  But how would I call it exactly?  What goes in the app part?  (Maybe submit that as an answer?)

Comment: `apps.get_model("auth", "User")`. I didn't submit it as an answer, because it's not the cause of your problem; but it might cause other problems later on.

Comment: That actually fixed my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like I just needed to get User the same way I got UserProfile:

```
User = apps.get_model("auth", "User")
```

Thanks to @Daniel Roseman

Full working code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import migrations


def create_missing_profiles(apps, schema_editor):
    UserProfile = apps.get_model("myapp", "UserProfile")
    User = apps.get_model("auth", "User")
    for user in User.objects.all():
        UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', '0004_auto_20170721_0908'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_missing_profiles),
    ]
```